# sagemaker.image_uris.retrieve: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packa

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sagemaker, docker-image

I have an issue while getting xgboost image URI. It is a function for generating ECR image URIs for pre-built SageMaker Docker images.

My code:

`region = sagemaker.Session().boto_region_name container=sagemaker.image_uris.retrieve("xgboost", region, "1.2-1")`

Output:FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/image_uri_config/xgboost.json'

Answer (score 0):

Is it feasible to upgrade sagemaker sdk or re-install it. The image_uri retrieval is [here](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/dev/src/sagemaker/image_uris.py#L244) and the json files are listed [here](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/tree/dev/src/sagemaker/image_uri_config)

You can check locally if you see those files in the site packages folder. example - /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/image_uri_config

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am using the latest version of the framework/model. For version specific, refer the docs.

The following snippet works and is the latest syntax as of 11/28/2022 :

`container = image_uris.retrieve(framework='xgboost', region=boto3.Session().region_name, version='1.3-1')`

Documentation [here](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/utility/image_uris.html)

Underlying function [here](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/4325fcdae8a574a381f8cb4a125e36fcf4785fab/src/sagemaker/image_uris.py#L34)